# Android Priority-Job-Queue keep retrying until success

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, android-priority-jobqueue

So I have to download a bunch of image files from a server and I'm using [Priority-Job-Queue](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue). So far seems to works fine and I'm using a simple `AsyncTask` for the downloading part.

Since I want the images to be downloaded **no matter what** I only added `RetryConstraint.RETRY` on `shouldReRunOnThrowable()` callback. I have also added `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission on `Manifest.xml`

Is this the right/best way so if there's any kind of problem and some images aren't downloaded due to an error, job-queue will try to download them again and again until the job is finished with success ?

Thanks!

```
@Override
protected RetryConstraint shouldReRunOnThrowable(@NonNull Throwable throwable, int runCount, int maxRunCount) {

    return RetryConstraint.RETRY;
}
```

Comment: Note: this library is deprecated now, use WorkManager instead (for persistent jobs). For non-persistent jobs, use Corouties as recommended here https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue/blob/master/jobqueue/src/main/java/com/birbit/android/jobqueue/Job.java#L239) there are `cancelForDeadline` and `getRetryLimit()` constraints, that you should satisfy in order to keep retrying your job.

For the ***first*** one you just **don't** `overrideDeadlineToCancelInMs` for `Params` object, so in that case `cancelForDeadline` is always false.

For the ***second*** one, you have to override `getRetryLimit` method in your job, like:

```
protected int getRetryLimit() {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

And ***finally*** in case if you reached retry limit, you can schedule your job again:

```
@Override
protected void onCancel(@CancelReason int cancelReason, @Nullable Throwable throwable) {
    if (cancelReason == CancelReason.REACHED_DEADLINE) {
        jobManager.addJobInBackground(new FetchImageJob());
    }
}
```

Now for me it looks like it will run until success.